# save a date from input into the database php

Tags: php, mysql

The input e.g 1327500671 is acquired during post method. I  would like to save it into the database date column defined as "registerDate Date".

I couldn't find what date/time function can do this. I can fix the Date type in DB back into varchar, which makes things easier but I still would like to learn what type of format is most used to save datetimestamp into the database in more realife applications, as I am thinking they won't save it as 1/25/2012 21:49:00, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest storing the timestamps in the database and using the PHP date() function to make them human readable as and when necessary:

```
$timeStamp = 1327500671 //a timestamp from the database
$registerDate = date("j-m-y H:i:s", $timeStamp)
```

Comment: :D Thanks but could you tell me why the timestamps ?

Comment: They are easier to work with than formatted dates. For example, if you want to know the date one day after, simply add 86400 to the timestamp, then convert to a human readable date.

Comment: I agree with Isiscode. You can also convert a timestamp to a time depending on the timezone you are located. For example the same timestamp means a different time UTC and a different in another location.

Comment: You can also do these things with a MySQL `datetime` column and the date functions in PHP and MySQL. Definitely consider storing the datetime in UTC.